# Is there any non zero $C^{\infty}$ function having zero derivatives at $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let us take a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. $f \in C^{\infty}$. $f^k (0) = 0$ $\forall$ $k \ge 0 \in \mathbb{Z}$. *Is $f (x) = 0$ $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$?*

My attempt:

The function $f$ has a Taylor series expansion around $0$ and so

$$f(x) = f(0) + \frac{f'(0)}{1!}x + \frac{f^2(0)}{2!}x + \dots$$

The coefficients are all zero and so the function $f \equiv 0$.

There should be some mistake that I do not know.

If such a non-zero function exists please give me an example.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: By the way you should write $f^{(k)}$ for the $k$-th derivative of $f$. The notation $f^k$ means $f$ applied $k$ times.

Comment: The function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ is not identically zero, yet all its derivatives are zero at $x=0$ [One has to separately define $f(0)=0$ for this example.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the taylor series of $f$ may not converge. If $f$ is analytic, then certainly what you said is true. Otherwise, you can only say that for each $k>0$,
$$f(x)=f(0)+f^{\prime}(0)x+...\frac{1}{k!}f^{(k)}(0)x^{k}+R_{k}(x)$$
where $R_{k}(x)$ is a remainder term. This term is $O(x^{k+1})$ so that when you divide by that term by $x^{k+1}$ the limit is bounded. For the examples above, this is s true for each $k$, since exponentials to negative powers decay much quicker than polynomials.

Comment: More precisely, I suppose you mean that the Taylor series may not converge to the desired function.

Comment: yes, that was a typo...thanks

Comment: @user43687 thank you for pointing it out. Nice information!

Answer (score 4):

Here's a couple:
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x}} & x > 0 \\
0 & x \leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
and
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & x \neq 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}.
$$
The existence of such functions show that even if it is $C^\infty$, it is not necessarily analytic.

Comment: Thank you Pratyush for giving examples.